# Warning generated due wrong strcmp parameter handling

Tags: c++, c, clang

So I have an

```
unsigned char * pMyPtr
```

assigned to something.

Then I want to compare this to an arbitrary string with

```
strcmp(const char* , const char* )
```

But when I do that, clang compiler tells me

> `warning: passing (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign`

How do I remove this warning?

Comment: The usage of `strcmp` is
`if (strcmp(pMyPtr, "String2") == 0)` That will be true condition if both strings are equal.

Comment: Not doubting that. I am asking if there is a way I can remove this warning.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `unsigned` in declaration of `pMyPtr`?

Comment: Yes, the code base is not mine, comes from a client.

Comment: @Ilya, it isn't even unsigned. Behind it, is a struct.

Comment: @juanchopanza should not it be `const char` instead of a `char`?

Comment: Given his comment that the pointer points to a struct, I withdraw my comment, since `strcmp` cannot be used to compare a struct with anything.

Comment: @user1343318 If it is indeed a struct, then your program is full of bugs.

Answer (score 6):

With all the comments to the question, I feel like I'm missing something.

I know that casts are unfashionable, but isn't the following a simple workaround?

```
strcmp((const char*) pMyPtr , whatever_is_being_compared)
```

Comment: Yes. And if you don't like swamping the client code with casts, hide it in a wrapper function that takes `unsigned char *` as argument.

Comment: But note that signed integer overflow is still undefined behaviour in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza: where would signed integer overflow come into play here?

Comment: Wouldn't interpreting an `unsigned char` of value greater than `numeric_limits<char>::max()` as a `char` (for a signed `char` implementation) constitute overflow? Or maybe I am just too confused this morning, in which case I apologize.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It's not casting the `unsigned char` to a `char`; it's casting the pointer to an `unsigned char` to a pointer to a `char`. In effect, that will reinterpret the bits in the pointed at byte array. I think that a `signed char` whose bits are all set is allowed to be a trap representation (at least on a one's complement machine), so the reinterpret_cast is technically unsafe, but in practice one's-complement machines with trapping 0377 characters are probably even rarer than machines which trap on integer overflow.

Comment: Even though `strcmp()` takes plain `char*` arguments, it defined to act on the characters as `unsigned char` anyway: "The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions `memcmp`, `strcmp`, and `strncmp` is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters **(both interpreted as unsigned char)** that differ in the objects being compared."

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Wearing the language lawyer hat, I don't think the fact that `strcmp` casts each (possibly signed) `char` to an `unsigned char` avoids the (highly theoretical) problem that the original `unsigned char` might be a trap representation if read as a `char`. That is, the language in the definition of `strcmp` still allows it to use either `*(unsigned char*)arg` or `(unsigned char)*arg` to do the reinterpretation, both of which are well-defined, afaik. But it's all dancing angels, no?

Comment: @rici I know it is casting a pointer. Which means you re-interpret the bits of an `unsigned char` as those of a (possible signed) `char` when you de-reference the data pointed at by the casted pointer. But if `strcmp` is designed to cope with this, my point is moot.

Comment: @rici: my understanding is that lvalue expressions with character type, whether signed or not, cannot trap (according to 6.2.6.1/5 in the C standard).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I wrote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24032322/1090079) *Q&A* to answer your question(s).

Comment: @rici I wrote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24032322/1090079) *Q&A* to answer your question(s).

Comment: @juanchopanza I wrote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24032322/1090079) *Q&A* to answer your question(s).

Comment: @juanchopanza The data is obviously strings. Have you ever heard of a symbol table using negative indices? Why would the unsigned char contain anything in that would get interpreted as a sign bit? If it did, there's a bug elsewhere in the code and not related to the strcmp call. In other words, if the unsigned char contained anything that would possibly be interpreted as a trap representation when converted to char, it seems unlikely that the value of the unsigned char could be used to represent a valid symbol, which is the whole purpose of it in this case.

Comment: @Lundin `unsigned char` can hold values that a `char` cannot. Overflowing a signed integer is undefined behaviour. I don't care much about the rest, I can't speculate about the contents of a block of `unsigned char` data.

Comment: @juanchopanza If you use unsigned char for strings, as must be the case if you are using strcmp, then it doesn't make sense to have the unsigned char holding anything that char cannot, _because the size and signedness of the char type is selected based on the local symbol table_. The char type is therefore large enough to print all the symbols you could possibly want. So if you store something larger than CHAR_MAX in your unsigned char, you have an application bug.

Comment: (And wearing the language lawyer hat, overflowing a signed integer does not necessarily lead to UB: the implementation could support negative zeroes. See C11 6.2.6/3.)

Answer (score 5):

> It isn't even unsigned. Behind it, is a struct.

This means that you cannot use `strcmp` here. You can use `strcmp` when the input data are null-terminated strings. That's not the case when the input data are structs. Perhaps you should consider `memcmp` instead, or perhaps you need to compare the structs as structs.

Comment: `memcmp` might cause problems, if there is padding on struct.

Comment: @user694733 True. The exact solution depends on info we don't have. We can be sure that strcmp is not it though.

Answer (score 1):

Clang can't convert from `unsigned char*` to `const char*`.
That because `unsigned char*` is different then `char*`.
By adding `unsiged` you make the range of `char` 0to255 instead of -127to127.

On the line where strcmp goes, you can typecast the unsigned char value with `(const char*)` which will work, because there it will be threated as a `const char*`. instead of `unsigned char`

Comment: `char` has implementation-defined signedness. It may be unsigned and range from 0-255 or it may be signed and range from -128 to 127 (assuming two's complement).

Comment: For C++, it treats `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` as three distinct different types.

Comment: @hlovdal Yes, i know. But i also mention about C.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel that warning does not have any side effect. you can ignore the warning like this:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4507 34 )
```

Comment: Disable warning messages 4507 and 4034.

Comment: Bad advice. Don't disable warnings if you don't know what this is about. Here obviously just the wrong tool is used. Using a string comparison function for binary data is just the wrong idea. When using the correct function (`memcmp`) there will be no warning since it has the correct signature.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I said, "If you feel that warning does not have any side effect", Yeah, memcmp is good way to go. :)