# Is it safe to cast an unsigned char* to char*, and treat the dereferenced pointer as if it really points to a char?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Following the question titled [**Warning generated due wrong strcmp parameter handling**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24030116/1090079), there seems to be some questions regarding what the Standard actually guarantees regarding value representation of character types.

---

#### THE QUESTION

This looks fine, but does the Standard guarantee that the *(1)* will always yield *true*?

```
char unsigned * p1 = ...;
char          * p2 = reinterpret_cast<char *> (p1);

*p1 == *p2; // (1)
```

Comment: `char const unsigned` sure is an unusual way to name the type.

Comment: why would you ever want to use `unsigned char` (to hold a character rather than a small integer) instead of `char`?

Comment: @Walter some find the representation of bytes as a range [0,255] more intuitive than the range [-128,127], myself included. Additionally, it can be good to explicitly show something is a byte (unsigned char), not a character (char).

Comment: @iFreilicht Granted. But I think he wants to interpret this as a character rather than a byte.

Comment: @walter when displaying as char and bytes (%02X) it is useful for avoiding sign extension issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### THIS MIGHT SURPRISE YOU,

but there's no such guarantee in the *C++11* Standard ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), nor in the upcoming *C++14* ([N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)).

```
char unsigned * p1 = ...;
char          * p2 = reinterpret_cast<char *> (p1);

*p1 == *p2; // (1), not guaranteed to be true
```

<sup>**Note**: it is implementation specific whether `char` is *signed* or *unsigned*; `[basic.fundamental]p1`.</sup>

---

#### DETAILS

The Standard guarantees that every character type shall;

- have the same *alignment requirement*;
- occupy the same amount of storage, and;
- that all bits of the storage occupied by a character type shall participate in the *value representation*, and;
- that the *value representation* is the same.

Sharing the same amount of storage, *alignment requirement*, and the guarantee about bit participation, means that casting a lvalue referring to one type (*unsigned char*), to another (*char*), is safe.. as far as the actual cast is concerned.

> `3.9.1p1` **Fundamental types** `[basic.fundamental]`
>
> > It is implementation-defined whether a `char` can hold negative values. Characters can be explicitly declared `signed` or `unsigned`.
> >
> > A `char,` a `signed char,` and an `unsigned char` occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements (3.11); that is, they have the same object representation. For character types, all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation.
> >
> > For unsigned character types, all possible bit patterns of the value representation represent numbers. These requirements do not hold for other types.

> `3.9p4` **Types** `[basic.types]`
>
> > The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of *N* `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T,` where `N` equals `sizeof(T)`. The *value representation* of an object is the set of bits that hold the value of type `T`.

---

#### SO, WHAT ARE THE PROBLEM(s)?

If we assign the maximum value of an *unsigned char* ([*UCHAR_MAX*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)) to `*p1` and `*p2` is *signed*, `*p2` won't be able to represent this value. We will overflow `*p2` and it will, most likely, end up having the value of `-1`.

<sup>**Note**: *signed integer overflow* is actually *undefined behavior*.</sup>

---

```
*p1 = UCHAR_MAX;

*p1 == *p2; // (1)
```

---

Both sides of `operator==` must have the same type before we can compare them, and currently one side is `unsigned char` and the other `char`.

The compiler will therefor resort to *integral promotion* to find a type that can represent all combined possible values of the two types; and in this case the resulting type will be `int`.

After the integral promotion the statement is semantically equivalent to `int (UCHAR_MAX) == int(-1)`, which of course is false.

Comment: Hmmmm... I had assumed that char was signed.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp `char` cannot have padding bits (will look where the standard says so). I'm not sure if `signed char` can, but if it can, then an implementation that gives `signed char` padding bits must make `char` unsigned. Regardless, `strcmp` doesn't actually use the `char` type of its parameters, it converts them back to `const unsigned char *` before comparing anything.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp 3.9.1p1: "For character types, all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation."

Comment: @hvd note that in the latest draft, only [unsigned narrow chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und) is guaranteed to not have undefined behavior when used containing an indeterminate value. Which indicates to me that only unsigned char is guaranteed to not have a trap representation.

Comment: @ecatmur as stated, `3.9p2` is about the possibility of storing bytes in a plain char array, not about reading them as if they were a plain char.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp What about reading §3.10/10? It clearly states that it is allowed to access the stored value through a glvalue of type (plain) `char`.

Comment: @Arcoth that doesn't prove that there can be no trap-values in `char`.

Comment: Minor nitpick, in the question there is no assignment, and no overflow. The values are not equal solely due to integer promotion rules and the fact that char can have negative values.

Comment: @MarcLehmann Why does there need to be assignment to be overflow?  The simple dereference and read of the `char*` results in an implementation-defined value, and it may be a trap value if `char` is signed (and hence cause the program to halt), or worse.

Comment: @MarcLehmann it's implementation defined whether a char can hold negative values, and the assignment is just to make the example easier to understand.

Comment: A trap value cannot (by definition) cause an overflow, it can trap. If it's implementation defined whether a char can have negative values, then char can have negative values, no?

Answer (score 14):

> ```
> strcmp (buf1, reinterpret_cast<char const *> (buf2));
> ```
>
> This looks fine,

It is. `strcmp` takes `const char *` parameters, but internally converts them to `const unsigned char *` (if required), so that even if `char` is signed and two distinct bytes can compare equal when viewing them as `char`, they will still compare different when viewing them with `strcmp`.

C99:

> **7.21 String handling `<string.h>`**
>
> **7.21.1 String function conventions**
>
> 3 For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

That said,

> but does the Standard guarantee that the *(1)* will always yield *true*?
>
> ```
> char unsigned * p1 = ...;
> char          * p2 = reinterpret_cast<char *> (p1);
>
> *p1 == *p2; // (1)
> ```

What you wrote is not guaranteed.

Take a common implementation, with signed `char`, 8-bit bytes using two's complement representation. If `*p1` is `UCHAR_MAX`, then `*p2 == -1`, and `*p1 == *p2` will be false because the promotion to `int` gives them different values.

If you meant either `(char) *p1 == *p2`, or `*p1 == (unsigned char) *p2`, then those are still not guaranteed, so you do need to make sure that if you copy from an array of `char` to an array of `unsigned char`, you don't include such a conversion.